# How to disable pag initiation from Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to remove the default features of Datatables as I don't need some of them.

I have created a table and gave a id. After that I use API method to handle the table. I can see there is search box and page initions for the table now. But I really need to remove them.

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ticketstable2').dataTable({

         "paging": false,
         "searching": false,

    });
}
```

[API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/)

Above code doesn't work. How to remove the page initiations?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to set up `dom` property ,look [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).
for example ,`dom` property for you will be like this

```
$('#ticketstable2').dataTable({

         "pagging": false,
         "searching": false,
          "dom": 't'

    });
```

where `t` stands for just table,please have a look [example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)